# Jenkins First Build - Parameter 'haystack' is null

Tags: jenkins, tfs, continuous-integration, devops, jenkins-tfs-plugin

nowadays i am trying devops-thing in the tfs. Currenttly I stuck at jenkins integration with tfs. Firstly I explain what I did.

1- Created 1 MVC project in .NET and push into TFS repo.
2- Created jenkins Item and Integrated this item with tfs via Tfs-Auth-Token

Everything was perfect until first push. After first push the code builded automatically but thrown error

I am getting this error on the build. But it seems like gives an error before building my code. I searched something on stackoverflow but any one has not shared anything. plz help

````
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Netphin
FATAL: Parameter 'haystack' is null.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'haystack' is null.
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.util.StringHelper.endsWithIgnoreCase(StringHelper.java:9)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamCollectionConfiguration.isTeamServices(TeamCollectionConfiguration.java:199)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamCollectionConfiguration.areSameCollectionUri(TeamCollectionConfiguration.java:191)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamCollectionConfiguration.findCredentialsForCollection(TeamCollectionConfiguration.java:310)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.AutomaticCredentialsConfigurer.getCredentials(AutomaticCredentialsConfigurer.java:27)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.createServer(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:479)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.checkout(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:313)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1818)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE```
````

Comment: Not sure but this appears to be an obscure error coming from JenkinsCI's `tfs-plugin`:  https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/tfs/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/tfs/util/StringHelper.java . Maybe worth filing an issue with their devs.

Comment: It has disappeared after reinstallation.